# Read Pandas csv export in Power BI

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi

I am trying to visualize Data from Pandas in Power BI. In order to load data in Power BI I export the Data using the DataFrame.to_csv() method, since the DataFrame has more than 2 million rows.

The problem: If I try to load the Data in PowerBI, the float values are not recognized by power BI. Is there any param that I have to change?

Thanks

Comment: How do the float values look in the outputted CSV?

Comment: The look norma. e.g. 0.22, 0.23 and so on. I think the problem is the float separator but I don't know how to change it

Answer (score 0):

I am a moron. You can specify

```
decimal =","
```